# Node module install error in Node (socket.io)

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, module, socket.io

Trying to install socket.io in Node results in error.
Other modules, like express, are working fine. Ive already tried reinstalling node, even went as far as system restoring to before installing node. The weird thing is that it worked last week, the first time i installed it. The code below is from installing socket.io via NVTVS for Visual Studio, the same error occurs when executing from terminal. I am working on Windows 7 64bit (6.1 build 7601).
I also cannot find the error log they are refering to at the ws directory, as there is none. Is anyone able to read this error message, or has experienced this problem before?

```
Registry url: https://registry.npmjs.org/
Current Time: 03.12.2014 10:02:02
Last Refreshed: 03.12.2014 08:32:19
Number of Results: 115824
====Executing command 'npm install socket.io --save '====

npm WARN package.json NodejsConsoleApp4@0.0.0 No repository field.
> ws@0.5.0 install c:\users\cyzla\documents\visual studio                     2013\Projects\NodejsConsoleApp4\NodejsConsoleApp4\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_ modules\ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)
> ws@0.4.31 install c:\users\cyzla\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\NodejsConsoleApp4\NodejsConsoleApp4\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)
npm ERR! ws@0.5.0 install: `(node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the ws@0.5.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the ws package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls ws
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program     Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "socket.io" "--save"
npm ERR! cwd c:\users\cyzla\documents\visual studio   2013\Projects\NodejsConsoleApp4\NodejsConsoleApp4
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.33
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm

====npm command completed with exit code 1====
```

Comment: I'm not sure that it will be the cause, but when it happened to me I needed to disable Windows' User Account Control (UAC), it was not allowing some file to be downloaded.

Comment: @Talysson I tried, but with no luck. Still getting the same error

Comment: do you have Python installed and in the PATH? WS needs it to compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it. I linked to 'c:/windows/system32/' in System PATH, which for some reason fixed it.